# How to move an object to the top of a DOORS module?

Tags: ibm-doors

I basically know how to move an object within a module

```
Object oMove = object(DoorsID, mBasicCurrent);
Object oPrev = object(DestDoorsID, mBasicCurrent);

// move after
move(oMove, oPrev);

// move below
move(oMove, below oPrev);
```

But I can not find, how I can move it to the first position in the module. I haven't found anything in the documentation, but I found somewhere a hint that there are three types of move (after, below and top), but I haven't found an example and didn't get it to work.

Can please someone show me how to move an object to the top of a module?

Answer (score 0):

Now, I am doing it indirectly like this:

```
Object oMove = object(DoorsID, m);
Object oFirst = first(m);
if (oMove != oFirst)
{
    move(oFirst, oMove);
    move(oMove, oFirst);
}
```

I move it behind the first and then the first behind the second. This shouldn't cause problems, because both objects have to be on level one as the first object.

Comment: @bjskistad, this is an answer, that solves my problem. Of course, I hope there is a better build in solution in dxl, that moves an object directly to the top. Do you have any experience with dxl?

Answer (score 0):

// declare variables

```
Module curMod = current
Object firstObj
Object secondObj
```

//the following code will move absolute # 192 in front of absolute # 1

```
secondObj = gotoObject(1,curMod)
firstObj = gotoObject(192,curMod)
move(secondObj, firstObj)
```